# Building a simple REST service using Web API 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Friends,

It's been several years since I last worked with the ASP.NET Web API framework. Even then I had developed with it minimally.

I have a requirement for a service that will allow for the creation of a new question, retrieval of all questions, and then retrieving a question by an eventId. The following code is my controller, model factory, and repository logic.

If someone wouldn't mind taking a look at the code, and offering their suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

### Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using QuestionDomain.Repositories;
using QuestionDomain.Services.DTOs;

namespace QuestionDomain.Services.Controllers
{
public class QuestionController : ApiController
{
    private QuestionRepository _repository;
    private ModelFactory _modelFactory;

    public QuestionController()
    {
        _repository = new QuestionRepository();
        _modelFactory = new ModelFactory();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/question")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(QuestionDTO))]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var questions = _repository?.Get();

            if (questions == null || !questions.Any())
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No questions to return");
            }

            var questionDtos = questions.Select(question => _modelFactory.Create(question)).ToList();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, questionDtos);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "An exception occurred." + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/question/{eventId}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(QuestionDTO))]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid eventId)
    {
        var _eventId = eventId;
        try
        {
            var question = _repository?.Get(eventId);

            if (question == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No question to return");
            }

            var questionDto = _modelFactory.Create(question);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, questionDto);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "An exception occurred." + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/question")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]QuestionDTO questionDto)
    {
        try
        {
            var _question = _modelFactory.Create(questionDto);

            if (_question == null)
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Question is null");

            var result = _repository.Add(_question);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "An exception occurred." + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

### Model Factory Code

```
using System;
using QuestionDomain.Models.models;

namespace QuestionDomain.Services.DTOs
{
    public class ModelFactory
    {
      public QuestionDTO Create(Question question)
      {
        var _question = question;
        var _questionDto = new QuestionDTO()
        {
            QuestionId = _question.QuestionId,
            AssetId = _question.AssetId,
            CustomerId = _question.CustomerId,
            DateCreated = _question.DateCreated,
            DateModified = _question.DateModified,
            EventId = _question.EventId,
            QuestionAnswer = _question.QuestionAnswer,
            QuestionTitle = _question.QuestionTitle,
            TimePosition = _question.TimePosition,
            UserFirstName = _question.UserFirstName,
            UserLastName = _question.UserLastName,
            UserEmail = _question.UserEmail,
            UserId = _question.UserId
        };

        return _questionDto;
    }

        public Question Create(QuestionDTO questionDto)
        {
            var _questionDto = questionDto;
            var question = new Question()
            {
                QuestionId =  Guid.NewGuid(),
                AssetId = _questionDto.AssetId,
                CustomerId = _questionDto.CustomerId,
                DateCreated = _questionDto.DateCreated,
                DateModified = _questionDto.DateModified,
                EventId = _questionDto.EventId,
                QuestionAnswer = _questionDto.QuestionAnswer,
                QuestionTitle = _questionDto.QuestionTitle,
                TimePosition = _questionDto.TimePosition,
                UserFirstName = _questionDto.UserFirstName,
                UserLastName = _questionDto.UserLastName,
                UserEmail = _questionDto.UserEmail,
                UserId = _questionDto.UserId
            };

            return question;
        }
    }
}
```

### Repository Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using QuestionDomain.Models.models;
using QuestionDomain.DataModel;
using QuestionDomain.Repositories.Interfaces;

namespace QuestionDomain.Repositories
{
    public class QuestionRepository : IQuestionRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Question> Get()
        {
            try
           {
            using (var context = new QuestionContext())
            {
                var questions = context.Questions.ToList();
                return questions;
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("A null exception occurred getting all the questions. " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An exception occurred getting all the questions. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public Question Get(Guid eventId)
    {
        var _eventId = eventId;

        try
        {
            using (var context = new QuestionContext())
            {
                var question = context.Questions
                    .Where(x => x.EventId == _eventId)
                    .Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();

                return question;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An exception occurred saving a new question. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public string Add(Question question)
    {
        var _question = question;

        try
        {
            if (_question == null)
                return "Question is null";

            using (var context = new QuestionContext())
            {
                context.Questions.Add(question);
                context.SaveChanges();
                }

                return "question saved";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            throw new Exception("An exception occurred saving a new question. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

General comments:

- Use the Visual Studio "usings / remove and sort" feature to organize your imports
- Use the Visual Studio autoformatter to fix some of your indentation issues
- Install and run StyleCop and follow most or all of its recommendations
- If and when you obey StyleCop's recommendation to move usings into the namespace declaration, the usings for your own namespace can be shortened.
- Your exception handling pattern is kind of a bad idea. Given the above, you should just let all of those exceptions fall through.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Will take a look at StyleCop.